# Issues Booting from Bios with Windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to instal Ubuntu on a hard drive in windows 8.1, however I have traditional Bios rather than the new UEFI. (checked by entering panther folder from computer) I can't force a boot from USB and can't click the del or f12 keys fast enough when starting up. (also have removed Hybrid Shutdown in windows 8.1)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted what system you have and which bios you are running. But try f2 when you reboot sometimes that's the key you need. (to get into bios) other wise just burn a dvd and install, efi boot works for Cd/dvd's.